# route traffic from VPN server LAN (cloud) peer to VPN client

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, routing, openvpn, ip-forwarding

I have set up a Google Cloud deployment roughly configured as such:

1. node B, which is at address 10.0.0.6 and default route is through 10.0.0.1
2. node V, which is a VPN server, on same subnet at 10.0.1.0

Separately, I have a nodes Q and Q' which is in my home network (behind router) and connects to the VPN as a peer. Q has static IP address 10.168.0.240, which is assigned by the VPN as a static IP.

Q' is irrelevant, except that Q and Q' are able to successfully communicate when connected to the VPN.

Through IP forwarding and iptables, I have been able to set it up such that the VPN allows traffic from the clients to use it as a gateway to the general internet, and I have confirmed that Q can address B directly in this manner (which is accomplished through openvpn's `push-routes` directive).

The problem I am having is like this: I would like B to be able to address Q directly. I don't especially care what IP address it uses to address it, but can't use port forwarding through a listener on the VPN machine. I hope to set up the routing tables, etc on B so that it addresses packets to 10.168.0.240 via the VPN server, and have the server forward those packets down its `tun0` interface.

I suspect that last part already works, but using `tcpdump` i can confirm that a request on B like `traceroute 10.168.0.240` never arrives at V -- UNLESS i include a directive like `-g 10.0.1.0`. However, a `traceroute 10.0.1.0` does reach V, and `ping 10.0.1.0` works as well.

B is configured like this:

`$ ip route list
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.1 dev eth0  scope link
10.168.0.0/24 via 10.0.1.0 dev eth0`

I suspect my intermediate level knowledge about routing is missing one critical piece. I thought perhaps the metric/preference settings, that I can't find much documentation on, would solve this; however, all sources seem to indicate that more specific routes are preferred. The third route seems the most specific and appropriate for this route.

How would I configure B to make sure its packets addressed to the virtual subnet are routed through the server? That might not be all that is necessary, but this seems like one concrete step that I am unable to solve so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the issue, and it is platform-specific (GCP).

On Google Cloud, there is a bespoke mechanism for building routes that use specific IPs or other instances as a nexthop router (some documentation [there](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-routes#canipforward)).

I had to use Terraform and set up a specific route in that way, and enable the special figure `CanIPForward` on both instances. After that, the `iptables` worked, and I didn't have to set special routing rules on either instance.